# Adobe Flash Builder: How to make a function to play embeded video starting from one second and ending in another?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, video, mxml

Adobe Flash Builder: How to make a function to play video starting from one second and ending in another? So I havein MXML simple video player tag. I need some function to play that video from second X to second Y and pause it. How to do such thing?

BTW: we asume file is embeded into SWF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using FMS?  not using FMS?  With FMS you would pass in netstream.play(file, start, duration);  If not using FMS, the conventional method (which is pretty awful) is to do something similar to:

```
stream.play(file);
stream.pause();

// wait for the time to be available, and then play

stream.seek(start);
stream.resume();

// listen for the end and then
stop();
```

If you have access to change your webserver, there are better plugins to handle on-demand seeking, take a look at:

Apache mod_flvx: http://journal.paul.querna.org/articles/2006/07/11/mod_flvx/
Nginx h264 module: http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/Mod-H264-Streaming-Nginx-Version2

or just google mod h264 and/or mod flv and your web server

Comment: not using FMS. we asume file is embeded into SWF (which is pretty awful but is normal for my project)

Comment: yikes.  Well if it's embedded I'm not sure how to access the video frames, I'm assuming Flash converts them into a long timeline, which at that point you'd have to read the framerate from loader.contentLoaderInfo.frameRate and numFrames to calculate your own timestamps .... Then a simple gotoAndPlay / gotoAndStop would work ....